# New language in Universal Dependencies

Tags: syntaxnet

I've added a new language in UD (Buryat) and now would like to parse it with SyntaxNet.  Could you, please, tell how is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow the instructions at
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/README.md#detailed-tutorial-building-an-nlp-pipeline-with-syntaxnet
on how to build an NLP pipeline with SyntaxNet.  We might also be able to train and post a model for you.